# Dynamic change on listview row layout affects other rows too

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am using ListView and there are several buttons on each list element.

when a button on a row is clicked that button should disappear. the clicked button disappears when clicked that's ok. the problem is some of the other list elements buttons are gone too.

for example, when I click 1st elements button it affects the buttons in the 6th, 11th, 16th elements too. also 7th elements button affects 2nd, 12th, 17th elements.

the reason is that the adapter doesn't create list element for all the elements in the data. it only creates several objects enough to show on the screen. as shown in the picture when going down in the list, top element becomes the last and its values are changed. so when I hide button in the first element the button in the 8th element (numbers are from the picture) is hidden too.

[image]

I can avoid to use copies of created items and create new item for each elements could be solution but it slows the application after viewing so many rows.

I've been looking for hours but couldn't find any solution. I hope someone knows any solution or at least suggest me a different kind of adapter, implementation or something.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of each element buttons state weather shown or hidden. in `getView()` method of the adapter check for the current element state then hide or show button accordingly. when using this method make sure to set each button state not only the one that should be hidden so when the view recycle, the view gets the new item state not the old one.

Comment: actually i am not only hiding a button. i also add new buttons and add new vote menu to that row. so other rows have that vote menu too. it seems i will handle each rows status and set their view again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Amal has part of your answer. When your adapter gets a getview call completely reinitialize the reused view.

As for your speed problem. Sounds like you want your adapter to load its data lazily. Your loading of that data is slow. Something has to give. A common solution to this problem is to load your data in a background thread.

Comment: i'll try to do it without threads. if it becomes really slow i'll try to use threads. thanks